# How to get AsyncStorage key name from FlatList item to delete?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, asyncstorage

I am generating a random key name for AsyncStorage each time user saves an item. These are then displayed in FlatList (using SwipeListView library for swipe to delete button). Now if I call          `await AsyncStorage.removeItem(key);` when the user taps "Delete", I presume the item will just disappear from the list. What I'm completely lost on is how I am supposed to get my random key name? Struggling to find much on FlatList and AsyncStorage, not sure what good practice is.

FlatList:

```
export default class RecentMealsScreen extends Component {
  
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state={
      meals: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getAllMeals();
  }

  getAllMeals = async () => {    
    try {
        const data = [];
        let keys = await AsyncStorage.getAllKeys();
        for (let inKey of keys) {
          let obj = await AsyncStorage.getItem(inKey);
          obj = JSON.parse(obj);
          data.push(obj);
      }
      this.setState({
        meals: data
      })
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error saving all meals. Error: " + error)
      }
    }

  
  renderHiddenItem = () => (
    <View style={styles.rowBack}>
            <View style={[styles.backRightBtn, styles.backRightBtnRight]}>
                <Text style={styles.backTextWhite}>Delete</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
  );

  deleteMeal = async (key) => {
    try {
         await AsyncStorage.removeItem(key);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error deleting Meal: ' + error)
    }
}


  // Get Meal IDs and display them in list
  render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <SwipeListView  
          data={this.state.meals}
          renderItem={ ({item}) => 
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Meal 
            image = {item.image}
            order={item.orderName}
            company={item.companyName} 
            price={item.price}
            dateTime={item.dateTime}
            notes={item.notes} 
            rating = {item.rating}
            />
            </View>          
          }
          disableRightSwipe
          renderHiddenItem={this.renderHiddenItem}
          rightOpenValue={-Dimensions.get('window').width}
          useNativeDriver={false}
          onSwipeValueChange={this.deleteMeal()}
          />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Save Logic:

```
saveMeal = async () => {

    try {
      let meal = {
        image: this.state.imageSource,
        orderName: this.state.orderText,
        companyName: this.state.selectedCompany,
        price: this.state.priceText,
        dateTime: this.state.dateTimeText,
        notes: this.state.notesTextField,
        rating: this.state.starCount
      };
      
      const ID = await Random.getRandomBytesAsync(16);
  
      await AsyncStorage.setItem(ID.toString(), JSON.stringify(meal)).then(() => {
        // Redirect to new screen
        Actions.recentMeals();
      })
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Save Meal error: " + error)
    }
 }
```

Comment: Just save the keys in your `data` list. Add 'inKey' as one of the properties of `obj`. Then you can call `deleteMeal` with `item.key' as an argument.

Comment: @giotskhada Great, thanks! How can I access item outside of renderItem though? I don't need to add anything else to my view, simply just call a function.

Comment: Figured it out.